Strange Multicolumn subsection formatting
I have a single part in my document where a strange format logic appears (picture).

Here is the code from this part>
\section{Projektdefinition und Lernziel}
\begin{multicols}{2}
\subsection{Themengebiet}
\noindent Some Text  
\subsection{Medienprodukt} 
\noindent some Text

\end{multicols}
\section{Recherche}

So nothing special. There are also other parts in the document with the same code structure. Therefore it must be some kind of weird text alignment rule, right?
Someone here who has faced a similar issue before?

From multicol.pdf:

In the second step (balancing columns) we have other bells and
whistles. First of all you can say \raggedcolumns if you don’t want
the bottom lines to be aligned.  The default is \flushcolumns, so TEX
will normally try to make both the top and bottom baselines of all
columns align.

So just add \raggedcolumns and TeX won't force the first column to fill the text height.

The subsection 3.2 doesn't fit into the first column (with at least 1 line after it), so LaTeX determines that the column needs to be broken before it. Due to the fact that your columns are so short and you have only a single paragraph and the heading 3.1 in the first column, the only place where LaTeX is allowed to stretch is after the heading (assuming you use a typical class). Even while this stretch is normally minimal and others will be preferred, given that it is the only one it gets all space (as you have flushcolumns in force) -- that gives you the result you see.
As @cfr said, you can use \raggedcolumns or use something like \vspace*{0pt plus 1fil} just before subsection 3.2
